# Form not searching database or displaying on page

Tags: php, html, mysql

What should happen:

The user types in their id into the box and click check. 
It searches through the database called "damp". 
The search looks in a table called "card" and in a specific field called "state_id".

If the value in state_id is 1 the form will echo back *pass*, if it is 2 it echos *canceled*, if its 3 it echos *expired* and if it can't find it, it echos *not found*.

What actually happens is that the form isn't searching properly and doesn't display anything. I tried to change it to a switch (below) instead of an if and now the form does not show.

```
    <? include('common.php') ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];


$sql ="SELECT state_id FROM card WHERE id = '$id'" ;
mysql_select_db('damp');
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
switch ($result)
{
case "1":
   echo "pass";
   break;
case "2":
   echo "canceled";
   break;
case "3":
   echo "expired";
   break;
default:
   echo "not found";
}

//echo $_GET['here']; // Prints the name of the page content
//echo $class_obj_id; // Prints the id number of the selected row
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<h2>Check Auth</h2>
<table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="50" align="center">ID</td>
<td><input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo($class_obj_id); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="check" type="submit" id="check" value="Check">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry changed the text . no error message , just dosent work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because `E_DOEST_WORK` is not a known php error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this :

```
$sql ="SELECT state_id FROM card WHERE id = '$id'" ;
mysql_select_db('damp');
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query( $sql, $conn ));
  while($result){
  switch ($result['id'])
  {
    case "1":
       echo "pass";
    break;
    case "2":
       echo "canceled";
    break;
    case "3":
      echo "expired";
    break;
    default:
     echo "not found";
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to do a mysqli_fetch_assoc to the $result

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
switch($row['state_id'])
```

Comment: I dont know if it works because the php page displays blank. Thats the other problem I have with this.

Comment: Try this in the first line to see the errors
    `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: iv added it , what is supposed to happen . Its still a blank page.

Comment: I i remove the last 3 lines , the page displays but i get a prase error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Users\sl12abw\Desktop\SAVE\mowes_vv\www\vf1-damp\check.php on line 58

Comment: its supposed to show the errors in the code.
The last error in line 58, its because you remove the `<?php } ?>` of the if statment

Comment: try to make a `echo "a";` after the include and see whats happen

Comment: okay , so i move the <?php}?> up above the form and the thing now shows on the page . The problem now is that the mysql query isnt searching correctly . it should be searching a table called card and in a specific field called state_id .